Azure Terraform deploy: HTTP response was nil; connection may have been reset
When I use my Terraform IAC to deploy some ACI instances on Azure, it succeeds about a quarter of the time but often fails with the following error
HTTP response was nil; connection may have been reset
Any suggestions how to succeed more consistently?

can you please provide a minimal code which reproduced the issue?

did you try using max_retries? since you are using the latest version already and also please share the code you tried @user2913094

Is the issue resolved? @user2913094

It seems to be azurem issue that has been resolved in Terraform v1.9.5 and azurerm v4.1.0 and -parallelism=5.

Thanks for your response ha36d. I have Terraform v1.9.6 and azurerm v4.3.0, so it must be something else...

have you tried to reduce the parallelism: terraform apply -parallelism=5 (Default is 10)?

Yes, I did. Unfortunately, it did not help either
